# Do I need to run a prepared query in Wordpress when I'm just matching table columns?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Simple question - I do understand that if I want to run this type of query in Wordpress:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE variable1 = $var1
```

...then I need to use 'prepare', like so:

```
$my_query = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableA 
WHERE variable1 = %s", $var1) );
```

However, when I want to do this type of query instead:

- join two tables on a column
- and NOT use a variable

like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB WHERE tableA.some_col = tableB.some_other_col
```

...'should' I:

1. still use some form of 'prepare' statement to safeguard against SQL injection
2. or is it ok to do the following:

   ```
   $my_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB WHERE 
   tableB.some_col = tableB.some_other_col");
   ```

Comment: If you're not passing in any parameters, you don't need to use prepared statements since there is no chance that user input will touch your database.

Comment: This becomes a code style issue more than a security issue.  As the answer(s) below indicate, you don't need it, but there *may be* some code style advantages to using it consistently.  Personally, I *only* use `$wpdb->prepare()` when I have parameters I'm passing in, but that is a code style decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need prepared statements there because there is no way that anyone could use this code for sql injection.

If you just select everything from two tables without giving any variable you can forget about prepared statements :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stick with

> $wpdb->prepare

even if you do not have any un-sanitized parameters to pass to the query.
There are few reasons why you should do that:

1. This is a best practice;
2. Consistency. If you will use the same approach for all your queries;
3. If you will need to pass a parameter to this query in future, it will be easier for you.

You find a discussion about this here [Should I use wpdb prepare?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16925/should-i-use-wpdb-prepare)

Comment: You are copying somone else's assertion that it's *best practice* to do this.  What would be good is if you could actually support the idea that it's best practice - does WP recommend it? Do you see that recommendation from some authoritative source? Or just another answer on SE?

Comment: @cale_b this is not a WP best practice but a _common best practice_ to use parametrized queries when querying a database [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) and [w3schools.com about SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). I do really believe that anyone should use parametrized queries and that does not apply only to WP.